# Filter IPs if they are in list of ranges

Tags: algorithm, azure-data-explorer, kql

In Kusto, I'm struggling with algorithm issue. I got big list of IPs (Azure Monitor), and a list of ranges to whitelist. How can I exclude rows of first list, if IP is in range of second list ?

Sure we will use `ipv4_is_in_range()` and `mv-apply` for this, yet I don't know how.

Sample items:

```
let ranges_to_whitelist = "['127.0.0.1', 10.0.0.0/28']";
let big_table_of_rows = datatable (ip_range: string) ['1.2.3.4', '10.0.0.254', '172.16.1.2', '10.0.0.1'];
```

Should yield:

```
datatable (ip_range: string) ['10.0.0.1'];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for track record, Kusto enriched with new function : `ipv4_is_in_any_range` making exactly this feature. Always better than workaround.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the requirement correctly, you'll need to first expand the array of ranges to whitelist (using `mv-expand` or `mv-apply`), and then apply the filter based on `ipv4_is_in_range()`:

```
let ranges_to_whitelist = dynamic(['127.0.0.1', '10.0.0.0/28']);
let big_table_of_rows = datatable (ip: string) ['1.2.3.4', '10.0.0.254', '172.16.1.2', '10.0.0.1'];
big_table_of_rows
| mv-apply ip_range = ranges_to_whitelist to typeof(string) on (
    where ipv4_is_in_range(ip, ip_range)
)
| project-away ip_range
```

| ip |
| --- |
| 10.0.0.1 |

or, for the opposite case:

```
let ranges_to_whitelist = dynamic(['127.0.0.1', '10.0.0.0/28']);
let big_table_of_rows = datatable (ip: string) ['1.2.3.4', '10.0.0.254', '172.16.1.2', '10.0.0.1'];
big_table_of_rows
| mv-apply ip_range = ranges_to_whitelist to typeof(string) on (
    summarize countif(ipv4_is_in_range(ip, ip_range))
    | where countif_ == 0
)
| project-away countif_
```

| ip |
| --- |
| 1.2.3.4 |
| 10.0.0.254 |
| 172.16.1.2 |

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer !
I tried to negate the "Where" clause to get all ips that doesn't match as well ; but It's not getting good results. did I miss something as well ?

Comment: answer was updated to include the opposite case