# Kusto query, comparing array of CIDR ranges to an IP

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to do something in Kusto similar to this post:
[Filter IPs if they are in list of ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564324/filter-ips-if-they-are-in-list-of-ranges)
but using the IP ranges from a publicly available list to compare to some logs.

Here's what I have tried, I believe the issue relates to me not knowing how to reference the "network" property of the external data.

I get a "Query could not be parsed" error.  Apologies for the formatting, I'm not sure how to make it respect line breaks.

```
let IP_Data = external_data(network:string,geoname_id:long,continent_code:string,continent_name:string ,country_iso_code:string,country_name:string,is_anonymous_proxy:bool,is_satellite_provider:bool)
['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geoip2-ipv4/master/data/geoip2-ipv4.csv'];
let testIP = datatable (myip: string) ['4.28.114.50','4.59.176.50']; //Random IPs in Canada
testIP
| mv-apply tmpIP = IP_Data.network to typeof(string) on ( 
    where ipv4_is_in_range(myip, tmpIP
    )
| project-away tmpIP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the OP question directly, however there is a great solution for this scenario, based on the **ipv4_lookup** plugin.

**See new answer**

---

For both options -
Since the CSV has header, so I added `with (ignoreFirstRecord = true)` to the `external_data`

**Option 1**

- testIP is defined as array (and not a single column table).
- The base table is `IP_Data` but the `mv-apply` is done on `testIP` array. This enables you to access values from both `IP_Data` and `testIP`

---

```
let IP_Data = external_data(network:string,geoname_id:long,continent_code:string,continent_name:string ,country_iso_code:string,country_name:string,is_anonymous_proxy:bool,is_satellite_provider:bool)
['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geoip2-ipv4/master/data/geoip2-ipv4.csv'] with (ignoreFirstRecord = true);
let testIP = dynamic(['4.28.114.50','4.59.176.50']); //Random IPs in Canada
IP_Data
| mv-apply testIP = testIP to typeof(string) on (where ipv4_is_in_range(testIP, network))
```

| network | geoname_id | continent_code | continent_name | country_iso_code | country_name | is_anonymous_proxy | is_satellite_provider | testIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.28.114.0/24 | 6251999 | NA | North America | CA | Canada | false | false | 4.28.114.50 |
| 4.59.176.0/24 | 6251999 | NA | North America | CA | Canada | false | false | 4.59.176.50 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12RT2/CMAzF7/0UubWVoB0I9qdop02TuCGuCEWh8Uq01K4St6XSPvxS6MS0W97PjuX3bIHFdiffFSvxKuDC4FBZqYNOELgn91V4dgarWQWEqgZpdGEp6JKQDQKyLEnDb9edjs0TFQG3yG6QxtO/9hv/0zwzXiokHGpqvWwcXYbiRGRH7hWDtYZh5J3R4K6lNDrEZ%20bGF3nuVJ9Vhs/tqfXgxnXCMllJdT6a8sA%20D05Ms5ybplvltfLB87X2l2el7%20Kj6MMgkZgKycGHcZ73UJLTISp2LaSbyIb8GDxvd4HpIdgwZXKIV9nyOVssVtn6IZ4FtX7JFk%20PozqmG5Hne4Wa6pC8FwbFm0KlVTTdIfoWdTdXTWOH%20%20jpwSR4aIA%20k1tWqSAUSX8GB2JcO%20QrDUqnsILk9mcmpjum6Q8aY3xs7QEAAA==)

---

**Option 2**

Cross join both tables (using a dummy column) and then filter the results

---

```
let IP_Data = external_data(network:string,geoname_id:long,continent_code:string,continent_name:string ,country_iso_code:string,country_name:string,is_anonymous_proxy:bool,is_satellite_provider:bool)
['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geoip2-ipv4/master/data/geoip2-ipv4.csv'] with (ignoreFirstRecord = true);
let testIP = datatable (myip: string) ['4.28.114.50','4.59.176.50']; //Random IPs in Canada
testIP | extend dummy = 1
| join kind=inner (IP_Data | extend dummy = 1) on dummy
| where ipv4_is_in_range(myip, network)
| project-away dummy*
```

| myip | network | geoname_id | continent_code | continent_name | country_iso_code | country_name | is_anonymous_proxy | is_satellite_provider |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.28.114.50 | 4.28.114.0/24 | 6251999 | NA | North America | CA | Canada | false | false |
| 4.59.176.50 | 4.59.176.0/24 | 6251999 | NA | North America | CA | Canada | false | false |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2VRy07DQAy8V%20o/%20NYGtQlF5RXECYTEDXFFaLXNWqkhsaNdpyESH89uWwSC44zHj/E0qPD4ZO6tWrgF/FD0bBvjIp4z6iD%20vQzqietFjcK2RUOubCTiSliJkdVU4vBb9cMm8ZGFSPesfjQU5I/8wP8SLygYy8JjK30wnZePsdyINIkPVrFpSDHxO3Lo96VsOnmZbVW7UBaFt0Nek277TR/Qp3viNXklbZFcBdRQRCvUnS2p262L1oZoel/7zedV2M1eYYiDYE41i8cH8kGfsRLv4q/U95jdTCdN/KBi0MenSKYpajcNwrwdqSvhYCmDl9k6P7vKV6t1fn46W0R0fp2vLi8Ser2Boni27KSNWQQghjvL1tnp5Dj4c58MO3B9245xz2o6%20YQ3icp3YndLzOhh/h3kf3kGwgeUGocteoTkMuZhiI23XOP%204gUcU8%20SMD75DStd2sGOh/aTL26707gxAgAA)

Comment: Both options work, I just need to find a way to use them at scale with a larger data set.  I suppose that may not be possible with the massive number of comparisons this requires.

Comment: Sure.  I want to correlate firewall log destinations to the corresponding countries.   If you take my original attempt using 'let testIP = datatable (myip: string) ['4.28.114.50','4.59.176.50'];' and imagine that having thousands of IP addresses to map, you get the idea of the scale I am trying to work with.  Something like
let source = FWLogs | TimeGenerated > ago(24h) | where ipv4_is_in_range(destinationIP, network)

Comment: Probably should have checked this first.  I have about 25k distinct IPs every 15 minutes, and the lookup table in my example from github has over 170k ranges.  On the bright side you showed me what I was doing wrong so your answer is still correct.

Answer (score 0):

**New answer**

---

Demo for 1M IPs, based on the [ipv4_lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-lookup-plugin) plugin

```
let geoip2_ipv4 = external_data(network:string,geoname_id:long,continent_code:string,continent_name:string ,country_iso_code:string,country_name:string,is_anonymous_proxy:bool,is_satellite_provider:bool)
['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geoip2-ipv4/master/data/geoip2-ipv4.csv'] with (ignoreFirstRecord = true)
| extend continent_name = coalesce(continent_name, '--- Missing ---');
let ips = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000000 step 1 | extend ip = format_ipv4(tolong(rand() * pow(2,32))));
ips
| evaluate ipv4_lookup(geoip2_ipv4, ip, network, return_unmatched = true)
| summarize count() by continent_name
```

| continent_name | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| North America | 399059 |
| Asia | 201902 |
| Europe | 173566 |
| South America | 33795 |
| Oceania | 13384 |
| Africa | 17569 |
| --- Missing --- | 226 |
| 160499 |  |

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA11SwW7bMAy9F%20g/8BancOI17SnDrr31sutQCIrNOkRlUaCopCn68aXcbkuqk/34qPceqYAKIzKljaN0uIdfgK%20KEn1wg1ffRNQjy8s2q1AcW6NGP6GjYRvY/nuOShGjup4H/Mv6j1byFwoGl6hycpT5G/0TPyO3lJ2PHE8Tl%20yS8Otpu2MOFc9eMQRSrPiBBpS5tLy%20%20rPYq6a87Trxx/VIui%207klGqH3Oz7nnqaqqMmrvP1Kuaupt8ttBz7Rxf9/mweIKjXQQNjZEFH0iy/saeZbBZqRQ03fd5aHGAy%20BG6NkHzD02l5UWFqvVCh4p5zoZ%2014sf15fBVsGpWx9k2UU8oHesBEfRwSCZ%20EJbkEZbn/MB8x0MuSfPCVrfWax7nmbjXLdUr1haJZwA4mPzaa92yztmJ5pzeYPPhQThNrjAvNLSc3Zo2it0MLXS2hBUItEV6LJ9Hu8mEMu0%20TFXMO8VBPdnb5N5QP6AgsWcgIAAA==)